# How to send client certificate to backend?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have created a small spring boot application containing a REST endpoint which is secured by x509 certificates.

With Postman I am able to call this REST endpoint. Therefore I had to disable "SSL certificate verification" and add the certificate for the service (Host, CRT file, KEY file and the passphrase). Of course Host is "localhost".

In the next step I would like to put WSO2 Api Manager between postman and my service.

So I published the API, imported the crt file of my service into WSO2 truststore.
In addition I set  require in axis2.xml.

Now I am calling the endpoint configured in WSO2 API Store and in the console I always get:
[2019-08-30 17:15:06,941] ERROR - SourceHandler I/O error: null cert chain
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain

**Update:**
I followed the instructions in the documentation but still it does not work. Now the exception is "Bad certificate".

To avoid misunderstanding I draw an overview:
[overview.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJsht.png)

So this is the current state I am experimenting on.
As you can see in the section below WSO2 should just forward the client certificates to the secured backend. 
And as you can see as well, I have multiple clients.

**Update 2**

I think the correct term for my use case is the so called "Mutual SSL between client and API Gateway". There are guides in the internet with custom handlers but this guides are not working because the certificate is always null.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `require=true` is not required if you want to authenticate backend with MTLS. (That configuration is used if you want to make Gateway API URL MTLS protected)

For your use case, follow this doc.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Mutual+SSL+between+API+Gateway+and+Backend

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately the doc did not helped. I updated my post and included a drawing of the current state to avoid misunderstanding.